# Extract text from all <li> tag contains <b> tag with text SKU

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to Extract text from all `li` tag contains  tag with text SKU.

```
<ul>
<li> 5.875 x 5.875</li>
<li><b>SKU</b>:        1TVN-11</li>
<li>based name</li>
<li>based name1</li>
<li>based name2</li>
</ul>
```

From above I want to extract the text "1TVN-11" but sometimes this `li` tag is not present. I am using XPath right now:

```
SKU = root.xpath("./ul/li/b[.='SKU']/following-sibling::text()[1]")
```

Comment: SO is for coding issues, where is your code/attempts ?

Comment: I want to Extract text from all <li> tag contains <b> tag with text SKU.

<ul>
<li> 5.875 x 5.875<\/li>
<li><b>SKU<\/b>:        1TVN-11<\/li>
<li>based name</li>
<li>based name1</li>
<li>based name2</li>
</ul>
From above i want to extract the text "1TVN-11". but some times this li tag is not present in some pages. i am using xpath right now.

Comment: SKU=root.xpath("./ul/li/b[.='SKU']/following-sibling::text()[1]")

Comment: Add it in your original post : https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48875911/edit

Comment: I don't know why my tags in description rendered in browser.

Comment: how can i convert the html into plain text ?

Comment: paste it, select it, then click on `{ }` button (code)

Comment: @GillesQuenot edited please check my question if you could please understand

Comment: You say that sometimes "this `li` is not present" but you don't say what you want done in those circumstances.  By being so unclear, even after receiving feedback, you've squandered the attention of many people who could have helped you by now.  Voting to close as unclear what you're asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do if `li` is not all the time there :

```
'//b[.="SKU"]/following-sibling::text()[1]'
```

`//` stand for *recursive* expression

Comment: but still that text after the bold tag can't be extracted.

Comment: So, there is a problem with your missing code. Add it to your post ! That's the very basic requirements to post a good question   
Please, [read _how to ask good questions_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Israrulhaq: This is as good of an answer you're going to get given the lack of clarity of your question.